# Asp.net core razor pages load partial page

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

I use asp.net core 2 new feature Razor pages.  in the _layout.cshtml.

```
 <body>
<div>
   @await Html.PartialAsync("_LayoutHeader") 
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the _layoutHeader.cshtml is page with code behind.

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@model Yiko.Ent.WebRazorPages.Pages._LayoutHeaderModel
```

and @RenderBody will load index.cshtml with pagemodel.

```
@page
@model Yiko.Ent.WebRazorPages.Pages.Home.IndexModel 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
}
```

run the project. throw a error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Yiko.Ent.WebRazorPages.Pages.Home.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Yiko.Ent.WebRazorPages.Pages._LayoutHeaderModel'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)

Comment: Pass the model `@Html.PartialAsync("_LayoutHeader", {your model}) `

Comment: And *this* is why Razor Pages suck, and why Web Forms should have been left in the dustbin of history, instead of resurrected as Razor Pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to the page, or you can make the core view code into a partial and call it from both.

Pages are not a replacement for partials or View Components.

Comment: Are there any plans to allow razor pages to be used as partials/replace View Components in future release? Thanks