# Error while using @{Html.RenderPartial in Razor pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

following the answer here on how to reuse HTML block on the new Razor pages, I get the following error:

>
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'xxxxx.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type xxxxx.Pages._mainMenu_Page'.

in `Index.cshtml`:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_mainMenu");}"
```

This is the `index.cshtml` file (part of - the relevant part):

```
page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
 }



<div class="row">
    <section class="parallaxBox">

        <div class="UpperMenu">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs">

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <h1><span>Menachem Design</span></h1>
            </div>



             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">


                  @{Html.RenderPartial("_mainMenu");}

            </div><!-- /col-lg-6 -->

        </div><!-- /.UpperMenu -->
```

and obviously this line causes the problem:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_mainMenu");}
```

and the view (_mainMenu) is:

```
@page


 <nav class="UpperNavigation navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     .... (the rest of the HTML code)
```

I tried to google it, as well as look here but didn't find answer
What's the problem?

Comment: Are you using Razor Pages here and not just pure MVC? Why do you have a `@page` tag in the partial view?

Comment: Also, you can simplify the code to just `@Html.RenderPartial("_mainMenu")`, no need for curly braces and semi-colon.

Comment: Can you try `Html.RenderPartial("_mainMenu",null);. I bet this will let the View Context know not to expect a model. It is probably clever and trying to match a model by the view name when the model is not specified.

Comment: @RossBush ViewData contains the Model passed to each view.  If the method (RenderPartial for example) does not specify a new model, the current model is passed.  The issue here is that WebPages (which is not MVC) uses @page to specify a *page*.  I'm pretty sure you can't specify a WebPage page as a page and a partial.  Removing `@page` would solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, only Razor Pages and not MVC - the reason is because it's a simple website and doesn't need the complexity of MVC. Therefore I'm using Razor Pages. I have '@page because you have to use it in the new ASP.NET core 2

Comment: @DavidG for RenderPartial I have to use the curly braces because it sends the html direct to the stream and not return a value

Comment: @RossBush I tried  '@{Html.RenderPartial("_mainMenu", null);}' still get the error

Comment: @RossBush I removed the '@page from _mainMenu and now it works. But now I'm confused. Because look what Microsoft writes in their documentation: '@page must be the first Razor directive on a page. '@page affects the behavior of other Razor constructs.' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/index?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I think this question has the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906846/asp-net-core-razor-pages-load-partial-page

Comment: @Tim Was not answered yet. I'm still confusing on why Microsoft stated you need to use '@page in each page, but then you get error and only if you remove the '@page the error is gone. I want to understand and know the reason

Comment: The answer is the first comment...pass the model.

Comment: The first comment asks if I'm using MVC or Razor pages. The answer is Razor pages. And this the reason why I'm using the @page. My first question was how to insert html blocks into Razor pages and the answer I got was to use the Html.RenderPartial which as I understand from your comment is part of MVC. Then, it's takes me to the original question: is there, and what's the right way to insert html blocks into pure Razor pages which use the '@page as Microsoft suggests. Therefore the confusion

Comment: @DavidG - Your first comment saved my day.  I was searching for this and it took me 2 hrs of googling. The error/issue is that when we create a new partial page in visual studio -  it is adding the '@page' directive even for the partial page types.  Thank you.